# Can data-role=collapsible be made to work with a h2 tag inside a header block?

Tags: html, mobile, semantics, jquery-mobile

Currently when I attempt to use data-role=collapsible there is nothing left (no button, link or content). According to the documentations it uses a h1-h6 tag but mine is inside a html5 header block.

Should I forget about the html5 semantics since this is a mobile site? Or should I attempt to make it work somehow, if so any ideas?

Link to docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/content/content-collapsible.html

Example of my current setup:

```
<article data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
  <header>
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- some data -->
  </div>
  <footer>
    <!-- some data -->
  </footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is built with progressive enhancement in mind, so it assumes you want your app to work in any device possible ("work" meaning just support basic features)

Try replacing your nicely named tags with DIVs and remove wrapper around H2. Should help.

Comment: I agree... I feel like maybe html5 semantics aren't of any benefit to mobile sites, especially if they won't be index by a search engine. (Not sure if search engines make much use of semantics yet but I'm sure they will in the future)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question about html 5 semantics though? I see this as a weakness with jQuery Mobile. Surely the implementation could be changed to include both <div>s and semantic html 5 markup. And also, why wouldn't search engines index mobile sites? What about responsively designed sites that use the same markup for all breakpoints of a site?

Comment: The question was about making it work, not about html5 semantics. Also - jQuery Mobile has changed since then and some elements are more flexible. new html5 markup might be problematic for some simple mobile browser and that's a fact. Nothing to do with responsive design for modern mobile browsers that are way more capable than FireFox 1.5 was